# looking for world map that give me coordinates for x,y - gps

Tags: c#, dictionary, gps

is there any world map (on web) that can give me x,y coordinates

for any place in the world ?

(i build Windows-mobile GPS program and i need to check it)

thank's in advance

Comment: x,y co-ordinates for any place on Earth? Not longitude and latitude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://maps.google.com/

Center the map, then click `link` in the top right. The lat/lng is in the url as the ll parameter

Answer (score 1):

Google maps would let you lookup or check coordinates from your program. Here is a good article that can detail how to obtain the coordinates inside Google Maps:

http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/find-longitude-latitude/

A few different methods are described in there.